# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter with that position [2] did not exist

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to run a. API program in SpringBoot in which I have a query.
Previously it was showing parseException error which I resolved but now this new error came.
This problem never arose in other queries, I have no clue what the problem is. please help.

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM tbl_abc WHERE UserId = ?1 AND EndTime != '' AND StartDate BETWEEN '?2' AND '?3' ORDER BY StartDate ASC,StartTime",nativeQuery = true)
List<abc> getabctLog(int userId, String fromdate1, String todate1);
```

I expected a list of details from the table for those conditions given in the query. But I received this:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter with that position [2] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [2] did not exist
```

Comment: any reason about using `'?2'` instead use `?2` without cotes it will automatically converted to  `'some value'`

Comment: well I use single quotes for STRING values i.e '?2' and for any integer only ?2.
If i remove single quotes for String values this error will come: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Answer (score 0):

I think your StartDate is of type Date but you put in a String. You need to change your code:

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM tbl_abc WHERE UserId = ?1 AND EndTime != '' AND StartDate BETWEEN '?2' AND '?3' ORDER BY StartDate ASC,StartTime",nativeQuery = true)
List<abc> getabctLog(int userId, Date fromdate1, Date todate1);
```